# Having trouble keeping track of a cell and making the cells range equal a new variable

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to choose a cell to keep track of while a loop moves down cell by cell checking for conditions. If the conditions are met I want the chosen cell to be filled in depending on the condition met. I keep getting run-time error '1004', "Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed" on line`Set TrackedCell = Range(cell)`. How do you keep track or record a previous cell in a loop?

```
Sub AutoFill()
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
'Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Get Range", Type:=8)
Set rng = Range("F36:F66")
For Each cell In rng
    If IsEmpty(cell) = True And IsEmpty(Range("B" & cell.Row)) = True Then
        If IsEmpty(cell.Offset(-1, 0)) = True Then
            Dim TrackedCell As Range
            Set TrackedCell = Range(cell)
            TrackedCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
            cell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            Do Until IsEmpty(cell) = True
                If IsEmpty(TrackedCell) = False And InStr(1, celltxt, "F") Then
                    TrackedCell.Value = "F"
                ElseIf IsEmpty(TrackedCell) = False And InStr(1, celltxt, "NE") Then
                    TrackedCell.Value = "NE"
                ElseIf IsEmpty(TrackedCell) = False And InStr(1, celltxt, "P") Then
                    TrackedCell.Value = "P"
                End If
            Loop
            'Dim Subtest As Range
        End If
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: You already have `cell`. I'm not sure why you need `TrackedCell`. But if you do, `Set TrackedCell = cell`.

Comment: Set TrackedCell = cell

Comment: Thank you the error went away, but I made 'TrackedCell' to act as the spot in the column I wanted filled in as 'cell' was used to move down rows.